# Getting Null from post data from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, tomcat8

```
    <center>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/LargeLandmarkListGet" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="SLLRID">SLLRID:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SLLRID" placeholder="Enter SLLRID...">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </center>
```

That is the particular definition of the action in the JSP.

```
String SLLRID = request.getParameter("SLLRID");
```

This is how I am trying to get it in the servlet, within the doPost method.  However, SLLRID is always null.  I've tried everything I can think of but I cannot get it to return the inputted value.  However, if I hardcode the value, everything works perfectly, so I think there is something wrong when communicating between the JSP and the servlet.

What I Have Tried:

- Changing the name in `for` in the `label` definition, so that `id` and `for` are named differently
- Adding an `id` value to the `button`
- Hardcoding the value to verify the servlet
- Trying a `get` rather than a `post` (though that seemed wildly inappropriate)
- Testing other servlets with the same JSP (this worked, though not with this particular submission id)
- Ensuring that everything that needed entries in web.xml had said entries made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form sends the data based on the `name` attribute. So instead put: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="SLLRID" name="SLLRID" placeholder="Enter SLLRID...">`